# How to deal with Current Sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

I have a fairly simple question. I just want to know if my work is correct, it seems too simple. I'm not sure how current sources work- do I have to combine them somehow? Here's the problem below:
[image]

Here's my work:
[image]

Comment: The problem with your work is that you didn't do any.  You assumed that the 4 amps from the source on the left divides evenly into R1 and R2.  Why?  On the right, you violated KCL at the junction of R2 and R3 where you have 3 amps arriving and only 2 amps leaving. You need to be more careful and redo the analysis. Hint: Since you need to find V1 and V2, write down all of the currents in R1, R2 and R3 in terms of V1 and V2.  Then use KCL at the 2 nodes to give you 2 equations for V1 and V2. Then you can solve for V1 and V2.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm completely at a loss. I guess the setup is confusing as I'm unsure which resistors are in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

Key:

To convert any given parallel combination of current source and a resistor, to a series circuit of a battery and a resistor
1. Multiply both the current source value and the resistor value to get the emf of the equivalent battery.
2. New resistance value is same as that of the old resistance value.

With that I am getting a different answer. Refer image below

[image]

Comment: V1 = 24-9 = 15 v. What you've called R1 is not R1!

Comment: So here the potential difference across R1 in the question is the potential drop across my battery and across the 6ohm resistor combined and hence 24V(from the battery) - 9V(drop due to the resistance) = 15V?

Comment: As it happens in this particular circuit, \$R_{TH}\$ is the same **resistance** as \$R_1\$, but it’s not the same **resistor** as \$R_1\$

Comment: ... so yes, it’s the voltage across the 24 V battery and 6 ohm combined.